# Making my Python code accessible to my guildmates' phones

Tags: python, sharing

I made some python code tonight that is able to calculate dps based off different stats, but I want my guildmates to be able to use this python code on their phones and/or computers. It is only a little over a page of code so it is a very small script. Is there a way I can make it a mobile app or make the code into a sort of bot that they can use on discord?

I have not tried to do anything on my own yet, as I want to ensure the safety of my information and keep their phones/computers safe from being harmed by any of my own potential accidental malpractice.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a web application using Flask or Django. This way, anyone can access the DPS calculator through a web browser on their phones or computers without needing to install anything.

And if you want to make a discord bot then you can use discord.py (search on the google, you will find many tutorials about it).

**For safety,**
In web application, make sure to use secure connections (HTTPS).
In Discord bot, ensure that your bot token is kept private.

Comment: Note: both options require you to host your "application" (whether website or discord bot) on some server. You can rent a virtual machine on some hosting service, and deploy the application here, it would be accessible via some IP address like `http://11.99.20.42/my_app`. Of course it usually costs money to host anything. There are free hostings, but assume that all data that passes through your application is leaked to those scammy hostings

Comment: You can also turn your own PC into a server of your own app, see https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27589/how-can-i-host-a-website-on-a-dynamically-assigned-ip-address. It's a bit inconvenient, if you turn off PC, users can't access. And usually your network provider doesn't give you a static IP address, so it's hard for outside users to connect to your PC. You can order your network provider to give you a static IP, it costs more money too. Also if you follow this path, be ready that one day your PC maybe DDOSed (basically overloaded with external request from malicious PCs)